# Show only desired label in contour plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
y = np.linspace(1,5,20)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X**3+Y**3
ax = plt.axes()
contours = plt.contour(X,Y,Z, 3, colors='black')

plt.clabel(contours,fmt = '%2.2f', inline=True)
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, 100, cmap='plasma',alpha=1.0)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.colorbar();
plt.show()
```

The above code gives the contour plots of Z, where the number of contours is user defined. However, the value of Z it takes is automated by using the numbers in plt.contour function. What I want in this code, is that the value of Z should be user defined (for example Z=70 labeled contour), and only one contour of that particular Z should be displayed. Please help.

Comment: `contours = plt.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=[70], colors='black')`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
contours = plt.contour(X,Y,Z, levels=[70], colors="black")
```

You need to pass a list with only the value(s) you want for the contour(s).

Full code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
y = np.linspace(1, 5, 20)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X ** 3 + Y ** 3
ax = plt.axes()
contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 3, levels=[70], colors="black") # <---

plt.clabel(contours,fmt = "%2.2f", inline=True)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap="plasma", alpha=1.0)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: output]

You could also do this with any number of contours.
e.g.

```py
contours = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 3, levels=[20, 30, 50, 100], colors="black")
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

you can pass an array of contour_levels as:

```
x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
y = np.linspace(1,5,20)
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = X**3+Y**3
ax = plt.axes()
contour_levels = [5, 20, 50, 100, 200, 300]
contours = plt.contour(X,Y,Z, contour_levels, colors='black')

plt.clabel(contours,fmt = '%2.2f', inline=True)
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, 100, cmap='plasma',alpha=1.0)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]